# htaccess redirect 301 (both www and non-www)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two domains:

http://www.domain.com
and
http://domain.com
each pointing to the same directory. Now I got a new domain (http://foo.com)

Unfortunately a catch all directive would not work, because names changed for subdirectories. I need about 20 single redirects, e.g.

```
/file1.html -> /newdir/
/x.html -> /y/
...
```

That means, both http://www.domain.com/dir1 and http://domain.com/dir1 should be redirected **permanently** to http://foo.com/newdir1. And the same with the other directories. How can I achive that via htaccess redirects?

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule in root .htaccess of `domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on

ewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://foo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder1(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: for each of the 20 folders? how would I add the other rules, just a rule for each subdirectory? I suppose the RewriteEnge on and Options... only go once?

Comment: i would suggest using a single line for each folder.